# Is there a way to pass a callers phone number in Google Analytics click-to-call events

Tags: events, google-analytics, onclick, analytics

Is there a way to pass/capture the callers phone number who clicks a button/link that is being tracked by Google Analytics events.

I've noticed in the reporting for click events that it tracks what landing page the caller came from, mobile phone type, browser type, gender and the list goes on.  But, what I really need to know is if there is a way to grab the callers phone number and include it in a report.

- Is there a report in Analytics that I haven't seen?

Comment: No within the regime of the Google TOS, which prohibits collecting information that might identify a user.

Comment: This is off topic as it's not related to coding, but note that you should not be collecting into GA any information that could be used to identify an individual, and I think an individual's phone number would unequivocally qualify as such.

Comment: @EikePierstorff thank you for your input... this ultimately answers the question if it's a TOS violation.